# Comment dire « fun » en français ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, demande-de-mot

Je n'arrive pas à trouver un bonne traduction pour le mot *fun*. J'ai trouvé beaucoup de gens disant le mot **amusant** mais je pense que celui-ci est plus proche de *amusing* (il y a un certain humour dans les situations où on dit *amusing*).

En français, comment puis-je dire *fun* ?

> Sa fête était *fun*.
>
> Apprendre le français est *fun*.
>
> Elle est *fun*.

Comment: On dit fun en fait. Entre amis hein. Sinon en situation pro on pourrait dire divertissant, ou meme amusant.

Comment: Version familière voire argotique: "kiffant/kiffante". J'entends ça de plus en plus...

Comment: "amusant" ou "plaisant", si vous visez un terme français international.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C'est un cas où aucune traduction exacte ou définitive n'est possible, en tout cas aucun mot français unique ne traduit tous les sens de l'anglais *fun*.

Il sera traduit différemment selon le contexte : ***drôle, marrant, sympa, rigolo*, ...** voire peut-être plus rarement *amusant* (plus formel, usage en baisse), *délire* (utilisé comme adjectif, registre familier), etc.

Mais souvent le mot n'est **pas vraiment traduisible seul** :

> We had a lot of fun at this party!

pourrait donner, selon les préférences des uns ou des autres :

> On s'est bien éclatés à cette fête !
>
> On a bien déliré à cette teuf !
>
> On s'est bien marrés à cette chouille !

ici c'est *to have fun* qui forme une unité de sens, donc on ne retrouve pas un équivalent du mot *fun* pris séparément. C'est un cas qu'on retrouve souvent dans d'autres usages de *fun*.

Enfin, il faut ajouter que le terme (anglais) a été **assez largement réapproprié par le français**, et qu'on l'entend énormément tel quel dans des phrases françaises.

Comment: Merci @Romain ! Vous êtes en train de m'aider beaucoup ! Je suis content de savoir que je peux utiliser **fun** sans traduction en Français :) J'ai cherché les mots que vous avez dit et éclater = burst|explode, teuf = chug (!), marrés = blast, chouille = partying like there's no tomorrow (loved this one!) - donc je pense que ils ne sont pas formel (ils sont argots). J'ai un examen de français en juillet et je pense que je ne dois pas utiliser ces expressions. Est-ce correct ou sont-ils socialment acceptable ?

Comment: Oui, j'aurais pu le préciser c'est vrai : les trois exemples que j'ai donnés pour traduire *We had a lot of fun at this party* sont sur le registre familier, à réserver à ses amis et connaissances proches. La meilleure manière de savoir ce qui peut se dire dans un groupe, c'est de d'écouter ses membres s'exprimer. Car les termes "à la mode" sont parfois très vite dépassés par d'autres, et les termes "jeunes" mais en réalité un peu vieillis produisent l'effet contraire à celui recherché : ça semblera artificiel et un peu ridicule.

Comment: @cldjr Pour un examen, mon vieil Harraps's suggère *fun* : amusement, gaieté, plaisanterie ; *to have fun* : s'amuser, se divertir ; le tout est complété par d'autres expressions idiomatiques. Si le contexte est (très) soutenu, il faudra s'en contenter, sinon les autres réponses sont acceptables selon leur contexte (à part la traduction de *fête* par *chouille*, qui semble être une expression très régionale)

Comment: @cldjr pour l'utiliser comme adjectif : *La fête était amusante, divertissante* ; les définitions  de amusant (http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/amusant/ ) sont très nombreuses, mais renvoient chacune à un contexte, à un usage particulier qui pourrait correspondre à une traduction de *fun* avec des exemples dans http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=fun

Answer (score 6):

À noter qu'au Québec on dit « C'est le fun » et non « C'est fun ».

Exemple :

> Cette soirée était le fun.

Plutôt que :

> cette soirée était fun.

C'était un petit funny fact.

Comment: Sorry for the tardy comment & upvote, but +1 for making the only allusion so far to the fact that “fun” is first & foremost a noun in both [English](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-says-fun-cant-be-an-adjective) and [French](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-definition/fun), and as such, to the extent that articles modifying nouns are generally not omitted in French, “Cette soirée était le fun.” (it's irrelevant, but I usually hear/say “Cette soirée était DU fun.”) is the most, if not only correct form to use, regardless of where in Francophonia one lives and speaks.

Comment: @PapaPoule Definitely not in France. Call “fun” an adjective if it makes you feel better but **Cette soirée du fun* or **Cette soirée était le fun* just aren't idiomatic. *Cette soirée était fun* is the only actual spoken French use you will encounter in France. (+1 for the info on Quebec use).

Answer (score 5):

None of the alternatives mentioned by @Romain mean *fun*:  *drôle*, *marrant*, *sympa*, *rigolo*.  They mean *funny*, except for *sympa*, which means *nice* or similar.

The French word that typically corresponds to the English word *fun* is **amusant**. And no, that does not mean *amusing* (un faux ami).

However, as @Romain pointed out, you must not expect to find a single French word that corresponds best to every use of *fun*.  In other words, it is a mistake to try to translate words one-to-one, with no attention to the context.  Typically you can use *amusant* for *fun*, but it is not always the best translation.

@Romain also correctly pointed out that *fun* has entered French, as a loan word.  However, as is typical for loan words, the meaning of *fun* in French cannot correspond exactly and always to the meaning of *fun* in English.

Comment: (+1) Very good remark about loan words rarely being perfect translations. That's counter-intuitive but very true. On another point, *fun* and *funny* have indeed different meanings, but don't you think there's some part of "meaning overlap" (sorry if this expression sounds strange I made it up to try to express my point) between the two? ...partly because many people have fun with.... funny things.

Comment: @RomainVALERI: Yes, I do think there is overlap between fun and funny.  In particular, funny things often provide for fun experiences.  And I hesitated to say that, for instance, *drole* is unrelated to *fun*.  Still, I think the overall message for native French speakers is that *fun* is not the same as *funny*. Fun is about having a good time, or is about play. It does not **necessarily** have anything to do with something that is funny.  We had fun at dinner last night, even though nothing funny transpired.  We had fun running that marathon, or dancing..., but no one was laughing.

Comment: @Drew “Sympa” does not mean “funny” and can certainly mean “fun”. “Amusant” is OK too but in my opinion it's not very different from “marrant” (so probably closer to *amusing* than you suggest) and not better than “sympa”.

Comment: @Relaxed: I did not say that *sympa* means *funny*. On the contrary, I said it means *nice* (pleasant, pleasing).  And I maintain that if you want to say that something is fun then you are far better off in general using *amusant* than you are using *sympa*. And as I said, there might well not be a single French word, including *amusant*, that fits *fun* (or *funny*, for that matter) in all contexts.  Certainly (IMHO), neither *sympa* nor *marrant*  does.

Comment: @Drew No but you did write that none of the alternatives mentioned by Romain means “fun” although he did mention both “amusant” and “sympa”, which are pretty close. “Amusant” is not bad but it's not much better than “marrant” if you want to avoid suggesting that something is “funny” (which is not to say that “marrant” is a good translation or that any of these words would fit in all contexts!).

Comment: I think “sympa” is a bit better in this regard and can mean “fun” nowadays (it also means “nice” when talking about a person but that's now a distinct meaning IMO). It would be an excellent fit in your earlier example: “le dîner d'hier était sympa”, whereas “amusant” would not. “Sympa” suffers from another problem: it's very casual and not as common as “fun” is in English so it's indeed difficult to use appropriately. I don't disagree with the rest.

Comment: @Relaxed: Romain mentioned *amusant* by way of **contrast** to the others he cited in bold, saying that it perhaps means fun more rarely.  I disagreed - it means fun more often than the others.  And I said that *sympa*, unlike the others Romain cited (in bold), does not mean *funny*.

Comment: @Drew No I believe that what he meant is that it has become rarer (because it feels very formal). I know (and acknowledged) that you did specify later in your answer that *sympa* does not mean *funny* but I still think that your first sentence is a bit unfair and that “amusant” suffers from the same problems than “marrant”, “drôle” or “rigolo”.

Comment: @Relaxed: I agree that one can find contexts where *sympa* means fun - as in the example you cite.  It fits less well when one really means ***FUN!***. To me, *sympa* is pretty mild when it comes to fun.

Comment: @Drew That's also true but that's also the case with all the suggestions (including my own). Incidentally, “amusant” is something I could also use to mean “Mmm, that's odd”.

Comment: Maybe, the only way to be really enthusiastic about something like a dinner would be “j'ai beaucoup aimé le dîner”, “j'ai passé un bon moment” ou “j'ai été très content de […]”. “Je me suis bien amusé” sounds either childish/dated or ironic (I had fun at the expense of others), “le dîner était amusant” is even more ironic and wouldn't be taken as praise.

Comment: @Relaxed: Agreed. This is also likely one of the reasons that *fun* in French cannot be expected to cover *fun* in English: Many French speakers will not be familiar with the different uses of English *fun*, so will not lend it such meanings in French.

Answer (score 4):

Les suggestions de Romain Valeri sont bonnes mais voici quelques propositions supplémentaires, pour éviter la confusion entre *fun* et *funny* (du moins formel au plus formel):

- Sympa
- Agréable
- Plaisant
- Divertissant

Ces mots sont cependant nettement moins courants que *fun* en anglais et peuvent être délicats à employer.