# «Le fun»: un adjectif introduit par «le»?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, langage-informel, évolution-récente

Selon le dictionnaire *Larousse*, [***fun***](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fun/35580) est un **nom masculin invariable.** Si l’on se fie à *Larousse* et au *Petit Robert*, il serait plus utilisé au Canada qu’ailleurs dans la Francophonie.

En tant qu’adjectif, il est décrit invariable par *Le Petit Robert*, avec un exemple, *des vacances **fun**,* dont la tournure ne serait jamais utilisée au Québec, du moins à ma connaissance. On y privilégierait plutôt *des vacances **le fun,*** tel que mentionné d’ailleurs en une  [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11933/13100) de ce site.

Il y a ici pour moi un point sensible. Je ne suis pas du tout convaincu que les utilisations de ce terme au Québec utilisent systématiquement la forme nominale. Le prétexte de l’introduction systématique du terme par un article (défini le plus souvent), qui pourrait clore la question, ne suffit pas à me convaincre. Je soutiendrais plutôt qu’il y a là un emploi adjectival qui maintient l’article défini.

Si je puis toujours admettre, **à la rigueur,** que *« C’était le fun ! »* est un emploi nominal (je ne le crois pas vraiment, je n’ai jamais perçu qu’il y eût là transmise l’idée d’une abstraction du fun dans l’absolu, comme il y en aurait pour *fête* dans *« C’était la fête ! »*, mais disons malgré tout que je juge la chose recevable), si je puis l’admettre, donc, je ne puis malgré cela concevoir de justification valable pour affirmer que *« des vacances le fun »* utilise un nom. On ne dira jamais, par exemple, *« des vacances la fête »* ou *« des vacances l’ennui »*, et on contrastera d’ailleurs ces fameuses vacances le fun avec des vacances ennuyantes, plates ou ratées d’autres années.

D’un autre côté, je puis penser à un style d’expression qui me semble plus présent aujourd’hui qu’auparavant en français, expression condensées qui s’introduisent elles aussi par un article défini :

- La honte !
- La poisse !
- L’angoisse !
- Le pied !
- etc.

Aucune de celles-ci ne semble avoir franchi le pas de l’emploi adjectival, mais elles semblent avoir parcouru au moins une partie du chemin.

- Si l’on admet que **le fun** puisse être, régionalement, utilisé en tant qu’adjectif dont la construction requiert l’article défini, peut-on mentionner d’autres exemples ? Si c’est un cas pour le moment unique, y voit-on une évolution de la langue qui puisse recevoir éventuellement d’autres cas ? Ou n’est-ce plutôt qu’une aberration, un élément condamné à demeurer seul ?
- Si au contraire on refuse de reconnaître la valeur adjectivale de **le fun**, comment décrit-on ses nombreuses utilisations dans le parler canadien-français ?

Comment: la présence de l'article au singulier alors que le nom qu'il modifie est au pluriel me ferait penser à une lexicalisation de "le fun", adjectif distinct de fun le nom. Pour tester sa nature adjectivale, quand est-til de sa capacité à apparaître devant un nom, d'être modifié par un adverbe ou d'apparaître dans une construction comparative ou superlative ? En gros, est-ce que "c'est la soirée la plus le fun de cette année" est grammatical?

Comment: @Eauquidort Je dirais que l'exemple ne ferait pas tiquer le Québécois moyen. Sans doute les puristes y trouveraient à redire, mais le tour est excessivement répandu, et dans tous les cas (puristes ou laxistes) plus naturel à l'oreille québécoise que la version qui n'utiliserait que «fun», sans «le».

Comment: Voici quelques autres exemples courants dans la langue orale québécoise: «ce voyage en train à vapeur est très très le fun pour les familles», «c’était bien moins le fun que la dernière fois», «un film tellement le fun qu’on remarque même pas qu'il date des années ’80», «on a eu une soirée drôlement le fun hier». En usage nominal, on modifie l’article au besoin: «on a eu beaucoup de fun hier, pis encore ben du fun en perspective aujourd’hui».

Comment: Dans un univers parallèle, le DHLF : « [...] alors que la francais du Canada, par emprunt oral, dit et écrit FONNE, n.m. [...] Au début du 21e siècle, on voit apparaître l'expression _pour le fun_ « pour le plaisir, sans raison utilitaire ». ». Étrangement, le GPCF contient les adjectifs _fonnant/fonneux_ pour plaisant, drôle : jamais vu ni entendu ça de ma vie ; il contient même _funny_ directement ; enfin il a le nom _fun_ avec l'exemple impayable (et absolument inusité pour moi) « avoir un fun de bossu » pour le _plaisir fou_.

Comment: Pour moi « c'est la soirée la plus l'fun de l'année » est parfaitement grammatical. Mais je pense que je dois prononcer soit « la plusse le fun » ou soit « la plus l'fun ».

Comment: @suiiurisesse Au XXIe siècle??? Fascinant de constater un tel décalage entre l'apparition et la constatation. Pareil pour moi concernant *fonnant/fonneux*, mais j'ai déjà entendu *funny* (prononcé à la française: fonné) par des gens de la génération de mes parents et plus vieux. Le fun de bossu est aussi inusité pour moi, mais me rappelle un peu la chance de cocu... Vos prononciations rejoignent les miennes: «la plusse le fonne» ou «la plu l’fonne».

Answer (score 1):

À propos du Larousse et du Petit Robert, j'aimerais faire deux remarques:

1. Même si ces dictionnaires s'adressent à toute la francophonie, il me semble qu'ils sont tout de même très franco-centriques. Personnellement, je ne les utiliserais pas comme référence pour des mots utilisés au Québec, en Belgique etc.
2. Les dictionnaires sont, par nature, en retard sur la langue parlée dans la mesure où ils n'acceptent de nouveaux mots que lorsque ceux-ci ont été utilisés pendant plusieurs années.

À propos de "fun", je l'ai toujours entendu utilisé en France principalement en tant qu'adjectif ("c'était (super/méga) fun !") si l'on parle pour soi ou son groupe d'amis. Dire "c'était **le** méga fun !" (mais pas "fun" tout court), implique plutôt que c'était fun pour tout le monde et pas seulement soi-même ou son groupe d'amis. C'est évidemment très subjectif.

Enfin, j'ajouterai que "fun" en tant qu'adjectif est différent de "funny" en Anglais, en France. "Fun" est associé à prendre du bon temps alors que "funny" est plutôt associé à la "drôlerie" d'une situation.